# Query not returning expected results when including an empty table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have three tables defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [garageInfo] ( 
    [griId] int identity(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [grId] int NOT NULL,
    [shId] int NOT NULL,
    [subEquipment] varchar(100) NULL,
    [make] varchar(50) NULL,
    [model] varchar(50) NULL,
    [serialNo] varchar(50) NULL,
    [pcr] varchar(50) NULL,
    [mop] varchar(50) NULL,
    [mopDesc] varchar(50) NULL
)
;

CREATE TABLE [car] ( 
    [crId] int identity(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [crDli] smallint NULL,
    [crName] varchar(60) NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE [garage] ( 
    [grId] int identity(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [grName] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [grDli] smallint NULL,
    [crId] int NOT NULL
)
;
```

The table `garage` and `car` contains data and returns expected records when I run the following query.

```
select * from garage p, car m WHERE p.crId=m.crId
```

But `garageInfo` is currently empty but will get filled with records by time, however I have following query that I run which given me `0` rows in return, How what I expect it to give me is all the columns of `garageInfo` as empty and two columns from other tables with their respective values, But it doesn’t not.

```
select * from garage p, car m, garageInfo gr WHERE p.crId=m.crId AND gr.grId=p.grId
```

Can anybody please help me what’s wrong here?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an `INNER JOIN` with an empty table. That will always give you 0 results (`INNER JOIN` gives you the "intersection" between the 3 tables. Because one of them is empty, the intersection doesn't exist).

If you want the info from garage and car, even without having info from garageInfo you have to do a `LEFT JOIN` with garage_info:

```
SELECT *
FROM garage p,
INNER JOIN car m ON p.crId = m.crId
LEFT JOIN garageInfo gr ON gr.grId = p.grId
```